# In CXF Is it possible to publish and subscribe Multiple Web Services one JMS queue?

Tags: cxf

in CXF is it possible to publish and subscribe Multiple Web Services one JMS queue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.

The behavior depend of the jms agent and configuration you use. But, if you want to do asynchronous WS over a broker this ability can be necessary.

You can look here [asynchronous-client-http-transport](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/asynchronous-client-http-transport.html) for more information on this.

The multi-ws on one queue can be usefull for some case of failover service or reporting.
If its become too complex you can look at camel [camel examples page](http://camel.apache.org/examples.html), to control finer patterns.